# Update buffer status in tabbar after saving and auto-compiling LaTeX file

Tags: latex, tabbar

I have customized `tabbar` to have a custom face for `tabbar-selected-modified`. The customizations work nicely for displaying the "modified" status of a buffer, and reverts to the default face when the buffer is saved.

I am now trying to extend `after-save-hook` to automatically compile LaTeX files on save. This also works correctly. But the problem is that the tabbar status (which was "modified" before I saved the buffer) for the buffer does not change back to the default (i.e., the buffer is saved) face.

Here is the code snippet that can be used to reproduce the problem.

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-user-dir (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/elpa/")
      package-enable-at-startup nil)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)

(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))

(use-package tabbar
  :ensure t
  :preface
  (defun tabbar-modification-state-change ()
    (tabbar-set-template tabbar-current-tabset nil)
    (tabbar-display-update))

  (defun tabbar-on-buffer-modification ()
    (set-buffer-modified-p t)
    (tabbar-modification-state-change))
  :init (tabbar-mode 1)
  :config
  (add-hook 'after-save-hook #'tabbar-modification-state-change)
  (add-hook 'after-revert-hook #'tabbar-modification-state-change)
  (add-hook 'first-change-hook #'tabbar-on-buffer-modification)

  (set-face-attribute 'tabbar-selected-modified nil
                      :background "#f2f2f6"
                      :foreground "dark green"
                      :box '(:line-width 1 :color "black" :style sunken)
                      :height 1.3
                      :bold t
                      :underline nil))

(use-package tex-site ; Initialize auctex
  :ensure auctex
  :mode ("\\.tex\\'" . LaTeX-mode))

(use-package tex-buf ; Requires tex and latex
  :config
  (setq TeX-auto-save t ; Enable parse on save, stores parsed information in an "auto" directory
        TeX-save-query nil)
  (setq-default TeX-master nil))

(use-package tex-mode
  :init (setq latex-run-command "latexmk"))

(use-package auctex-latexmk
  :ensure t
  :config
  (auctex-latexmk-setup)
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              (setq TeX-command-default "LaTeXMk"))))

(add-hook 'after-save-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when (string= major-mode "latex-mode")
              (TeX-command-menu "LaTeXMk"))))
```

To reproduce the problem, start with `emacs -Q`, evaluate the snippet, then open a LaTeX file and modify the buffer. You will notice that the tabbar face will change. Then, save the buffer. This will also trigger LaTeX compilation (with `latexmk` in this example). So far so good. But the problem is that the **tabbar face does not revert back to the default (i.e., saved) face/state**.

I have tried calling `tabbar-modification-state-change` in `after-save-hook`, but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: Check the modified status of the buffer after run your AUCTeX gizmo -- `(buffer-modified-p)` -- perhaps the buffer has been modified slightly by said AUCTeX gizmo -- e.g., with a text-property or something that doesn't look obvious.

Comment: How do I check that? Should I evaluate `(buffer-modified-p FILE)` in `*scratch*`?

This is what I did:

    (add-hook 'after-save-hook
              (lambda ()
                (when (string= major-mode "latex-mode")
                  (TeX-command-menu "LaTeXMk")
                  (if (buffer-modified-p)
                      (message "buffer is modified")
                    (message "buffer is not modified")))))

It prints "buffer is modified." But I don't think that is correct, since the tabbar face gets updated to indicate a saved buffer when I reload the file.

Comment: Depending upon how quickly the background process is running, your code may work.  Otherwise, you may need to attach your test to the sentinel exit code -- I'm not familiar with all the stuff that AUCTeX does and when it does each thing-a-majig.  The easiest way to test is just save the buffer, let your AUCTeX gizmo do its thing and then in the same buffer that contains the supposedly wrong tabbar indicator, type `M-x eval-expression RET (buffer-modified-p) RET` and see if it returns `nil`.  If it does, then we move on to PLAN B (whatever that may be).

Comment: The *optional* argument to `buffer-modified-p` is BUFFER-OR-NAME, so you could also evaluate from `*scratch*` using `(buffer-modified-p (get-buffer BUFFER-OR-NAME))`  The easiest is just to use the buffer-name -- FILE (all by itself), on the other hand, would not work.  But there are other functions to obtain the buffer or buffer-name from the file . . . but that's beyond the scope of what we need to do.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I evaluated `(buffer-modified-p)` and it returns `nil`. So the issue should be in redrawing the tabbars properly after the `after-save-hook` is run. Note that the tabbar indicators are properly updated after a save if I do not have this LaTeX hook enabled.

Comment: If you evaluate `(tabbar-display-update)` in the window with the wrong tabbar indicator after running the AUCTex gizmo, does that cause tabbar to correctly update?  `M-x eval-expression RET (tabbar-display-update) RET`

Comment: No, evaluating `(tabbar-display-update)` does not resolve the issue.